# Eclipse crashing on startup(eclipse.exe has stopped working),any solution?

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse

**Crash Report** :

```
 Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
    Application Name:   eclipse.exe
    Application Version:    0.0.0.0
    Application Timestamp:  4fad6d40
    Fault Module Name:  eclipse.exe
    Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
    Fault Module Timestamp: 4fad6d40
    Exception Code: c0000005
    Exception Offset:   00075400
    OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
    Locale ID:  1033
    Additional Information 1:   0a9e
    Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
    Additional Information 3:   0a9e
    Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy         statement offline:

```
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

    **Eclipse.ini file** :
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
    -product
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256M
    -showsplash
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vm
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx256m
    -Xmx256m
    -Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

Comment: Goto command prompt and navigate to path where you have installed eclipse say C:\Eclipse and execute the command "eclipse.exe -clean"

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: please help me.It has not resolved yet.

Comment: try changing the workspace or try downloading new eclipse package

Answer (score 1):

That might be due to low heap size. try increasing `Xmx256m` to `Xmx512m` or some higher value.